# Rotation problem using addplot3

Tags: pgfplots

Here is my code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
    view={120}{20},
    axis lines=center,  
    ticks=none,
    xmin=-3,xmax=3,ymin=-3,ymax=3, zmin=-1, zmax=4,   
    xlabel={$x$},xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},anchor=south east},
    ylabel={$y$},ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},anchor=west},
    zlabel={$z$},zlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},anchor=south},
]
    \addplot3 [blue, thick, samples=100, samples y=0, domain=0:2] ({x*cos(pi/3)},{x*sin(pi/3)},{x^2});  

\end{axis} 

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And here is my image.
[image]

This doesn't appear correct as the curve should be rotated pi/3 and be closer to the yz-plane. What have I done wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably wanted to add `trig format plots=rad` so that the trigonometric functions get interpreted as you intended. If you don't, you rotate only by `pi/3 degree~1 degree`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[trig format plots=rad,
    view={120}{20},
    axis lines=center,  
    ticks=none,
    xmin=-3,xmax=3,ymin=-3,ymax=3, zmin=-1, zmax=4,   
    xlabel={$x$},xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},anchor=south east},
    ylabel={$y$},ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},anchor=west},
    zlabel={$z$},zlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},anchor=south},
]
    \addplot3 [blue, thick, samples=100, samples y=0, domain=0:2] ({x*cos(pi/3)},{x*sin(pi/3)},{x^2});  

\end{axis} 

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! That really helps. Thanks.